# Making ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body) throw error in golang

Tags: unit-testing, go

For some reason, I cannot seem to get `ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)`, where `res` is the `*http.Response` returned by `res, err := hc.Do(redirectRequest)` (for `hc http.Client`, `redirectRequest *http.Request`).

**Testing strategy thus far**

*Any time* I see `hc.Do` or `http.Request` in the SUT, my instinct is to spin up a fake server and point the appropriate application states to it. Such a server, for this test, looks like this :

```
badServer := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { 
    // some stuff
    w.Write([some bad bytes])
}))
defer badServer.Close()
```

I don't seem to have a way to control `res.Body`, which is literally the only thing keeping me from 100% test completion against the func this is all in.

I tried, in the `errorThrowingServer`'s handler func, setting `r.Body` to a stub `io.ReadCloser` that throws an error when `Read()` is called, but that doesn't effect `res`.

Comment: There are no bad bytes. Any byte is a valid byte in an arbitrary byte stream.

Comment: I meant when we unmarshal them :P

Comment: How exactly are you testing this? Swapping the response Body with a stub that throws an error on reaad does indeed cause `ioutil.ReadAll` to fail. https://play.golang.org/p/ZhkyijksQ7j

Comment: All of that logic is happening inside the function I'm trying to test. The function, which is a middleware redirect function, does so much other stuff, before it does hc.Do. My issue is that i have, because of how the source code is written, absolutely no way to touch res. It is not a parameter being passed in, nor is it generated from any business dependencies.

Answer (score 12):

You can mock the body. Basically body is an io.ReadCloser interface so, you can do something like this:

```
import (
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)

type mockReadCloser struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *mockReadCloser) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    args := m.Called(p)
    return args.Int(0), args.Error(1)
}

func (m *mockReadCloser) Close() error {
    args := m.Called()
    return args.Error(0)
}

func TestTestingSomethingWithBodyError(t *testing.T) {
    mockReadCloser := mockReadCloser{}
    // if Read is called, it will return error
    mockReadCloser.On("Read", mock.AnythingOfType("[]uint8")).Return(0, fmt.Errorf("error reading"))
    // if Close is called, it will return error
    mockReadCloser.On("Close").Return(fmt.Errorf("error closing"))

    request := &http.Request{
        // pass the mock address
        Body: &mockReadCloser,
    }

    expected := "what you expected"
    result := YourMethod(request)

    assert.Equal(t, expected, result)

    mockReadCloser.AssertExpectations(t)
}
```

To stop reading you can use:

```
mockReadCloser.On("Read", mock.AnythingOfType("[]uint8")).Return(0, io.EOF).Once()
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could find perusing the source files for all of the working parts, the only way to get `http.Response.Body.Read()` to fail is commented here:

https://golang.org/src/net/http/response.go#L53

> The response body is streamed on demand as the Body field is read. If
>   the network connection fails or the server terminates the response,
>   Body.Read calls return an error.

Or there is the possibility in `ioutil.ReadAll()` for it to return `bytes.ErrTooLarge` here:

https://golang.org/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go#L20

> If the buffer overflows, we will get bytes.ErrTooLarge. Return that as
>   an error. Any other panic remains.

Comment: How can we make `res` such that `res.Body` has causes a buffer overflow. I'm talking about from the testing environment.

Comment: @MikeWarren presumably by using a `bytes.Buffer` that is large enough to trigger this condition. https://golang.org/src/bytes/buffer.go#L140

Comment: From where!?!?!

Comment: `resp.Body` could be reassigned to such a `bytes.Buffer`. Or you could find some reliable way for your `errorThrowingServer` to terminate the response as in the first quote, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Scratch the `bytes.Buffer` option, that only panics with that error when `Grow` is called, so that is off the table. You will have to figure out a way for your `errorThrowingServer` to either terminate the network connection, or terminate the response, which I haven't the faintest idea how to accomplish. Perhaps the handler could be refactored in a way that allows you to test with a passed in `http.Response.Body`, which would allow you to fully mock a failing response? Just a thought.